# Preventing updation of records through a POST request in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using `spring-data-rest` in my Spring Boot app and I have noticed a weird behaviour in POST requests.

If I make a POST request to my `http://<basepath>/<repository>` endpoint with my body containing the id value, then Spring attempts to update the record with that ID value. But if the version field of that record is non zero, then such a POST request returns an error

```
Object of class [com.foo.bar.schema.entity] with identifier [c6aba26a-79a9-34e4-a520-b447e446c2bd]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.foo.bar.schema.entity#c6aba26a-79a9-34e4-a520-b447e446c2bd]
```

Getting a solution to this error would be nice but I would rather not have someone updating records through a POST request by passing the identifier of the record. I have PUT/PATCH for that.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Consider adding custom validation handler to stop such request(i.e. reject all POST request that has an identifier for the record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to handle this. I am using a custom `PermissionEvaluator` where I am autowiring `HttpServletRequest` and then in the `hasPermission` method I am checking to see if `request.getMethod()` is POST and the entity has no ID.

```
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    public CustomPermissionEvaluator(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        if (targetDomainObject instanceof TableEntity) {
            TableEntity entity = (TableEntity) targetDomainObject;
            if (HttpMethod.resolve(request.getMethod()) == HttpMethod.POST && entity.getId() != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```